Popup window on CmdLineEnter and CmdLineLeave
I'm trying to write some autocommands that 'syncs' the command line with a popup window so I can see the currently entered command without moving my eyes to the corner of the screen. It looks I should be able to achieve this with CmdlineEnter, CmdlineLeave, and CmdlineChanged.
For some reason, the popup_create below works only once - when I open Vim and begin to type a command, the popup window shows up. When I leave the command line, the popup window closes. However, when I subsequently try to do this again, the popup doesn't appear anymore. This is strange because popup_create is returning nonzero, so it seems the popup window is being created but somehow not shown.
On the other hand, if I explicitly open the command-line window with q:, the popup window successfully appears. But, when I leave the command-line window with :q, the window stays on the screen and I have to clear it with :call popup_clear().
vim9script
augroup MyCmdlineGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineEnter : {
        g:my_winid = popup_create('hello world', {})
        echom $'created popup with id = {g:my_winid}'
    }
    autocmd CmdlineLeave : {
        popup_close(g:my_winid)
    }
augroup END

What's the cause of this behavior? From reading :h autocmd I'm getting the sense that Cmdline[Enter|Leave] is distinct from Cmdwin[Enter|Leave], but from the code snippet above that doesn't seem to be the case.

I found this post from some years back. Looks like redraw solves the issue. But unsure of any performance considerations involved.

Post an answer below if you have a solution!
